# Mysql 5.5 - Prepared Statement instance count runaway (millions)

Tags: java, ibatis, mysql-5.5

If anyone has experienced this or has any ideas it would be greatly appreciated...

I'll get right to the point:
The system in question uses java6, tomcat6 and ibatis

Since upgrading the database from Mysql5.1 to Mysql5.5 the system has become unstable.
Upon looking at jmap histo and analyzing memory dumps with jhat it is clear that the problem has to do with the JDBC side of the app.

The system does on average 3,000 selects/inserts/updates per second and it its busiest time of the day the Prepared Statement instance count is between 10 and 30.  The highest count we've seen during normal operation is just over 50.

Whats weird is that there is no pattern to the crashes, the system has crashed multiple times in the space of an hour and other times days could pass between crashes.

The highest instance count observed during the crash was over 5 million.

---

Here is some jhat data for JDBC4PreparedStatement from one of the memory dumps
This dump was taken as we picked up the start of the crash (only 200k instances at this point)
[image]

Comment: A bit cocky, but: do you close all the resources? 200k ResultSets... looks like you don't.

Comment: "A bit cocky"

Apologies if I sounded "cocky", not my intention I guess a failed attempt to be concise...
I'll double check, in the few places we directly create queries and execute them...

With the exception of 1 place in the app as well as some admin gui's our repository layer only uses ibatis so closing connections/resultsets etc should be done implicitly

Comment: No, I meant my question may be a bit cocky. Don't want to offend you. ;)

Comment: 5M instances with 3k requests per second means the statements are around for >~25 minutes. Either your gc is not working or something prevents the PreparedStatements & ResultSets from being dumped.

Comment: I've looked and the particular (legacy) class that doesn't yet use ibatis, creates the connection in a try block and closes everything in a finally block.

Comment: What I can't get passed is that if their is a problem in code (and I'm not disputing that possibility) then this would have happened before moving to 5.5 and it never did

Comment: Maybe you can use some of this: http://mysqlblog.fivefarmers.com/2012/07/05/whos-leaking-prepared-statements/ to find out what the database says.
Another thing: you are using dbcp, right? Which configuration are you using? Specifically, did you set `poolPreparedStatements` to `true`? Although, this wouldn't explain the number of `ResultSet`s.

Comment: On re-reading your answer, I wonder what do you mean with crash? What happens exactly? How about a thread dump from the time of the crash - does that show anything suspicious?
Is it possible that you are accessing the database recursively? I don't know how ibatis works and when it frees the resources, but I just can't imagine how you get such an absurd amount of PreparedStatements.

Comment: Thanks for the link, will try it.
We are using JDBC, as to the exact configuration on production, I'll need to get one of the sys-admins to get that from live...
Comparing histo's taken 1 minute apart, the PS count goes from < 30 to 2 million in the space of 1h 45m.
By crash I mean it runs out of memory, does millions of FGC's and the system dies.